# Почему работает не правильно моя программа?

Tags: python, итераторы

Делаю вот этот [номер](https://stepik.org/lesson/24464/step/4?unit=6769) . Пока что получается не очень

```
class multifilter:

    def judge_half(pos, neg):
        return pos >= neg

    def judge_any(pos, neg):
        return pos >= 1

    def judge_all(pos, neg):
        return neg == 0

    def __init__(self, iterable, *funcs, judge=judge_any):
        self.l = iterable
        self.f = funcs
        self.judge = judge
        self.i = 0

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):

        pos, neg = 0, 0
        if self.i >= len(self.l) - 1:
            raise StopIteration
        for i in self.f:
            if i(self.l[self.i]) == True:
                pos += 1
            else:
                neg += 1
        if self.judge(pos, neg) == True:
            self.i += 1
            return next(self)
        else:
            self.i += 1
            return self.l[self.i]
```

Но он выдает: *фильтр работает не правильно*. Я, скорее всего, не правильно понимаю принцип работы итератора. Вот что я думаю: когда я пишу `for i in multifilter(iterable, funcs, judge_any):` я пишу `for i in iter(multifilter(iterable, *funcs, judge_any))` и на каждом проходе цикла вызывается `next()`. Но что происходит, когда я пишу `list(multifilter(iterable, funcs, judge_any))`? Подскажите что-нибудь почитать или посмотреть по итераторам. Только не habr! Их абстрактные классы меня только запутали

P.S я знаю, что меня просят реализовать это все на `yeld`, но пока не изучу основы не хочу лезть в дебри

Comment: Вывод через принт довольно быстро помогает разобраться с работой программы. Вместо ссылки на задачу лучше приводить текст задачи. И желательно найти то место, работа которого отличается от ожидаемого и уже его проверять. Почитайте как [задать хороший вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) и [как создать минимальный достаточный пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Интересная задачка...

А попробуйте так:

```
class multifilter:
    def __init__(self, iterable, *funcs, judge=None):
        # iterable - исходная последовательность
        # funcs - допускающие функции
        # judge - решающая функция

        self.funcs = funcs
        self.iterable = iterable

        if not judge:
            judge = multifilter.judge_any

        self.judge = judge

    @staticmethod
    def judge_half(pos, neg):
        # допускает элемент, если его допускает хотя бы половина фукнций (pos >= neg)
        return pos >= neg

    @staticmethod
    def judge_any(pos, neg):
        # допускает элемент, если его допускает хотя бы одна функция (pos >= 1)
        return pos >= 1

    @staticmethod
    def judge_all(pos, neg):
        # допускает элемент, если его допускают все функции (neg == 0)
        return neg == 0

    def __iter__(self):
        # возвращает итератор по результирующей последовательности
        for value in self.iterable:
            pos = 0
            neg = 0

            for func in self.funcs:
                if func(value):
                    pos += 1
                else:
                    neg += 1

            if self.judge(pos, neg):
                yield value
```

Пробуем:

```
def mul2(x):
    return x % 2 == 0

def mul3(x):
    return x % 3 == 0

def mul5(x):
    return x % 5 == 0


a = [i for i in range(31)] # [0, 1, 2, ... , 30]

print(list(multifilter(a, mul2, mul3, mul5)))
# [0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10, 12, 14, 15, 16, 18, 20, 21, 22, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 30]

print(list(multifilter(a, mul2, mul3, mul5, judge=multifilter.judge_half)))
# [0, 6, 10, 12, 15, 18, 20, 24, 30]

print(list(multifilter(a, mul2, mul3, mul5, judge=multifilter.judge_all)))
# [0, 30]
```